# Como desserializar symfony 3 un json a entidad

Tags: php, symfony3, serialización

Tengo la siguiente entidad:

```
    class Alumno
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $nombre;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="apellido_1", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $apellido1;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="apellido_2", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $apellido2;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ImplikaAssert\IsValidIdNumber
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="dni", type="documento_identidad", length=20)
 * @Type("string")
 */
private $dni;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="fecha_nacimiento", type="date")
 * @Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'>")
 */
private $fecha_nacimiento;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="telefono_1", type="telefono", length=18)
 * @Type("string")
 */
private $telefono1;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="telefono_2", type="telefono", length=18, nullable=true)
 * @Type("string")
 */
private $telefono2;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="direccion", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $direccion;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="poblacion", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $poblacion;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Provincia")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="provincia_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $provincia;
```

.....

con sus get y set correspondientes. Al ser symfony 3 uso el 
use JMS\Serializer\Serializer; para serializar y deserializar

el tema es que quiero usar un array del estilo

```
$json = array(
    "nombre"=>"Alumno de prueba",
    "apellido1"=>"Apellido1prueba",
    "apellido2"=>"Apellido2prueba",
    "dni"=>"11110000R",
    "fecha_nacimiento"=>"1978-12-12",
    "email"=>"emailprueba@emailprueba.com",
    "telefono1"=>"666666666",
    "telefono2"=>"766666666",
    "direccion"=>"c/prueba 123",
    "poblacion"=>"",
    "provincia"=> "Valencia",
    "codigopostal"=> "20600",
);
```

Para crear el objeto, pero la provincia no se exactamente como hacer àra que deserialice automáticamente. Tengo que hacer un deserializador personalizado, o algo? mas que otra cosas por no hacer esto.

```
$arrayjson = json_decode($json,true);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
if (isset($arrayjson["nombre"]) and !empty($arrayjson["nombre"])) {
     $entidad->setNombre($arrayjson["nombre"]);
}
if (isset($arrayjson["apellido1"]) and !empty($arrayjson["apellido1"])) {
    $entidad->setApellido1($arrayjson["apellido1"]);
}
if (isset($arrayjson["apellido2"])) {
    $entidad->setApellido2($arrayjson["apellido2"]);
}        
if (isset($arrayjson["email"]) and !empty($arrayjson["email"])) {
    $entidad->setEmail($arrayjson["email"]);
}
if (isset($arrayjson["telefono1"]) and !empty($arrayjson["telefono1"])) {
    $entidad->setTelefono1($arrayjson["telefono1"]);
}
if (isset($arrayjson["telefono2"]) and !empty($arrayjson["telefono2"])) {
    $entidad->setTelefono2($arrayjson["telefono2"]);
} 
if (isset($arrayjson["direccion"]) and !empty($arrayjson["direccion"])) {
    $entidad->setDireccion($arrayjson["direccion"]);
}
if (isset($arrayjson["poblacion"]) and !empty($arrayjson["poblacion"])) {
    $entidad->setPoblacion($arrayjson["poblacion"]);
}
if (isset($arrayjson["provincia"]) and !empty($arrayjson["provincia"])) {
    $entidad->setProvincia(
        $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Provincia')->getByNombre($arrayjson["provincia"])
    );
}        
if (isset($arrayjson["observaciones"]) and !empty($arrayjson["observaciones"])) {
    $entidad->setObservaciones($arrayjson["observaciones"]);
}
if (isset($arrayjson["dni"]) and !empty($arrayjson["dni"])) {
    $entidad->setDni($arrayjson["dni"]);
}        
if (isset($arrayjson["codigoPostal"]) and !empty($arrayjson["codigoPostal"])) {
    $entidad->setCodigoPostal($arrayjson["codigoPostal"]);
} 
if (isset($arrayjson["fecha_nacimiento"]) and !empty($arrayjson["fecha_nacimiento"])) {
    $entidad->setFechaNacimiento(date_create($arrayjson["fecha_nacimiento"]));
}
```

}

que me parece una guarrada cuando existe un deserializador. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado algo que puede ser la respuesta en este enlace.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051659/jmsserializer-deserialize-entity-by-id
, lo unico que ahora me provoca otra duda, si hago un handler, ese manejador se ejecuta siempre, o puede haber alguna manera de ejecutarlo o no en función de un parametro.

Me imagino que si, siempre y cuando lo meta en alguna variable de entorno. pero espero la respuesta. no se si me he explicado correctamente.